# Pentaho Kettle: how to pass variable from transformation to another transformation inside job

Tags: pentaho, kettle, spoon

I have two transformations in the job.
In the first trasnformation - I get details about the file.

Now I would like to pass this information to the second transformation, I have set variable in the settings parameters of the trasnformation #2 and use Get Variables inside - but the values are not passed.

See attached sample: https://www.hightail.com/download/bXBiV28wMVhLVlZWeHNUQw

LOG_1 - displays file time, however LOG_2 and LOG_3 are not producing any value.

How can I pass variable across transformations and to parent job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try checking the box in the second transformation as below image:

[image]

2. Remove all the logs from the Job file you shared.

You may try reading this [blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/tag/copy-rows-to-result/).

Hope this will resolve your issue :)

Comment: thanks for your help. It worked. In parallel I found the other way, to use "get rows from result" step in second transformation.

Comment: Can you please expalin your way volder